# TemplateColumn with button and form only returns name of record not content

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I am trying to add a button with some functionality in a table that returns some info to the view using a POST:

```
class ProductTable(django-tables2.Table):
    Template = (f"""<form action="/product_all/" method="POST">{{% csrf_token %}}
                        <button> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="{{ record.get_store_id }}"/>view</button>    
                    </form>""") 

view = TemplateColumn(Template)
```

But when printing the request I get:

```
<QueryDict: {'store_id': ['{ record.get_store_id }'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...']}>
```

instead of the value.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new at Django, but I think you need another set of {}

```
Template = (f"""<form action="/product_all/" method="POST">{{% csrf_token %}}
            <button> 
                <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="{{{ record.get_store_id }}}"/>view</button>    
            </form>""")
```

so the end result of the template is:

```
<form action="/product_all/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <button> 
         <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="{{ record.get_store_id }}"/>view</button>    
</form>
```

Right now it is writing:

```
<form action="/product_all/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     <button> 
          <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="{ record.get_store_id }"/>view</button>    
</form>
```